# Torsion-free nilpotent Group

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups, nilpotent-groups

I am looking for  a short proof to the following fact:

> In torsion-free nilpotent group we have: an non-trivial element  cannot be conjgate to it inverse.

I know very little about nilpotent torsion-free group,one of their properties is that they have unique roots; i.e. for all $n \ge 1$, $x^n=y^n \Rightarrow x=y$.

Thanks in advance to anyone who is willing to help :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a torsion-free group, and suppose that some non-trivial element $x \in G$ is conjugate to its inverse. So there exists $y \in G$ with $y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}$.

Let $H = \langle x,y \rangle$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $x$ and $y$. Then $y^2$ centralizes both $x$ and $y$, so $y^2 \in Z(H)$. Since $y$ does not centralize $x^k$ for any $k \ne 0$, $x^k$ cannot be a power of $y$, and hence $\langle x \rangle \cap \langle y \rangle = 1$.

Hence $Q = H/\langle y^2 \rangle$  is generated by elements $\bar{x},\bar{y}$ of orders $\infty$ and $2$ with $\bar{y}^{-1} \bar{x} \bar{y} = \bar{x}^{-1}$, so $Q$ is the infinite dihedral group, which is not nilpotent, because it has trivial centre.

So $G$ is not nilpotent.

Comment: @DarekHolt thank you a lot; why  $\bar{x},\bar{y}$  are of orders $\infty$ and $2$

Comment: $|x|=\infty$ and $\langle x \rangle \cap \langle y \rangle =1$ imply $|\bar{x}| = \infty$. We have $\bar{y}^2=1$ and $\bar{y}$ does not centralize $\bar{x}$, so $|\bar{y}|=2$.

Comment: It is not clear to me why $y^2$ centralizes $x$. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: $y^{-2}xy^2 = y^{-1}x^{-1}y=x$.